# Paul's yacht will have arrived __ Hawaii by the end of the next March

Tags: prepositions

I came across a sentence that says "... will have arrived at Hawaii ...".
My question is why is it 'at'? I thought in might be better.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion; both 'at' and 'in' are equally acceptable. 'At' is possibly slightly old-fashioned.

Comment: It depends how you view Hawaii: a single state or a group of islands. If the port were more specifis, e.g., Honolulu, I'd probably say "at", but as @MichaelWokeHarvey states, for Hawaii, either could be used.